# MS SQL Server - MERGE operation with linked server table skips more than 99% of the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, merge, linked-server

I have a linked server for Oracle database. Source table in Oracle database contains more than 14 million of rows. I do merge with table in SQL Server using next command:

```
WITH SRC AS
(
    select * from [LINK_ORA]..[TEST].[SOURCE_TABLE]
)
MERGE INTO [TARGET_TABLE] AS [Target]
USING SRC AS [Source]
    ON [Target].Id = [Source].ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
    Target.IsDeleted = 0,
    Target.Attribute1 = Source.ATTRIBUTE1,
    Target.Attribute2 = Source.ATTRIBUTE2,
    Target.Attribute3 = Source.ATTRIBUTE3
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT(
        IsDeleted,
        Id,
        Attribute1,
        Attribute2,
        Attribute3
    )
    VALUES(
        0,
        Source.ID,
        Source.ATTRIBUTE1,
        Source.ATTRIBUTE2,
        Source.ATTRIBUTE3
    )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    UPDATE SET
    Target.IsDeleted = 1;
```

After the merge I found that only 51276 rows were loaded to target table. Why can this happen?

Comment: Because the rest matched and didn't need to be inserted?

Comment: Why you are using cte for source table ? and if both source and Target  id has same datatypes and non null-able columns, all records are matched

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The rest don't matched, I even delete all rows from target table before merge.

Comment: I'm not sure. Is the source unique on ID?. I don't use merge much. I prefer seperate insert/update statements